# Install fabric.js on node.js in a Windows environment

Tags: windows, node.js, fabricjs

I am trying to install fabric.js on node.js. I put in the command to do the installation as given in [this document](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/):

```
npm install -g fabric
```

But the installation fails with the error message "Can't find Python executable". Here is a screenshot showing the error:

[image]

I saw that the installation failed doing a rebuild of node-gyp, and so I tried manually installing node-gyp. The manual installation of node-gyp completed successfully, but this did not help with the installation of fabric.js.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this issue to get fabric.js installed in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 1):

Know this is old, but for those that see something similar.

As the initial error reports:

1. Make sure you have python installed

   https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
2. Make sure you have python in your path after it has been installed.